# Changed behavior in wine application menus

Tags: xubuntu, wine, xfce, menu, appmenu

Usually wine start menu entries are created under Wine\Programs in the main menu.
And those files are sourced from ~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs.

I recently deleted some menu entries but must have deleted something important because now I'm getting a different behavior.

Files are being read from ~/.config/menus/applications-merged
and ~/.local/share/desktop-directories.

And the applications in the menu are all being dumped into the main folder Menu/Wine/("Everything Right Here").

I have tried just deleting *everything* and purging and reinstalling wine, but the behavior persists.

How do I restore the much simpler and cleaner behavior I'm familiar with?

The desktop in question is XFCE.

Answer (score 0):

XFCE4's Whisker menu by default has a setting under 'properties' called 'Show menu hierarchy'.

Setting that causes the Programs folder to reappear.

Otherwise by default XFCE4's Whisker menu does not support nested menus and will group all of Wine's start menu entries together in the same folder.

This behavior isn't present under XFCE4's normal menu.